# How to create a simple help page for an Excel VBA add-in

Tags: vba, excel

I have created a small add-in for my client. It adds 2 buttons to the toolbar and works OK. Now I'd like to add a third button to display the version number and a small help text (15 lines).
I wonder what is the easy way to do this. Options I can think of:

- Insert (copy) a sheet with the help & version in the current workbook (efficient and easiest to do, but a bit rude and intrusive)
- Create a VBA form with the help text in a label control, and a OK button (very nice, but label content cannot be formatted AFAIK)
- write the info to a local HTML file and open that one (perhaps the more versatile?)

Any (other) suggestion ?
Note: I have no admin rights on my pc, so solutions involving additional software are excluded.

Comment: How about using a `WebBrowser` control in the userform? This way you can format your content.

Comment: @Arul great idea, thanks (did not know it could be done). I stored the html is a cell. Do you perhaps have a better idea ?

Comment: Is it possible to edit the html stored in a cell once you have saved the file as an addin? I was unable to do when I tried. The sheets were just not visible.

Comment: @Arul no issue as long as you don't try to `select`. I use sheet.codename rather than name. WIll put my code as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code of the UserForm I created, as per @Arul 's suggestion.

```
Option Explicit

Private helpFileName As String

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    helpFileName = Environ("temp") & "\test.htm"
    writeHelpFile
    WebBrowser1.Navigate "file:\\" & helpFileName
End Sub

Private Sub writeHelpFile()
    Dim fso As Object, Fileout As Object

    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set Fileout = fso.CreateTextFile(helpFileName, True, True)
    Fileout.Write Sheet4.Range("A1")
    Fileout.Close
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Terminate()
    Kill helpFileName
End Sub
```

Comment: Just curious, but, would you mind posting an image of the final look of your form? I'm wondering how it looks and if it looks cool. 100% curious. If you can't, no problem :)

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns Can't upload it, but it's just a form with 1 rectangular WebBrowser control, and  that's it. Not even a close Button (there is the top right red 'x' for that). Very happy with the process which could be improved to handle different contents quite easily..